# JPA/Hibernate doing update in table without any command

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa

Well, I work with JSF + Hibernate/JPA, I have the following code:

```
  public void loadAddressByZipCode(ActionEvent event){
    Address address = boDefault.findByNamedQuery(Address.FindByZipCode, 'zipCode', bean.getAddress().getZipCode());

    if (address == null){
      //This zip code not exists in db
   }else{
      bean.setAddress(address);
   }
  }
```

This method above is called in every "onBlur" in inputText component in XHTML page, this inputText have the property value like this: "#{addressMB.bean.address.zipCode}"

So, when user (in XHTML page) type a new Zip Code this value is setted in "bean.getAddress().setZipCode()" and i search for this value in Database. But debugging my application i discovered that when i do "bean.getAddress().getZipCode()" the Hibernate launch a "update address set ..." in my DataBase. How can i prevent this and why this happens ?

EDIT 1:
This is my real method implemented

```
public void carregarLogradouroByCep(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        List listReturn = getBoPadrao().findByNamedQuery(
                Logradouro.FIND_BY_CEP,
                new NamedParams("cep", bean.getLogradouro().getCep()));

        if (listReturn.size() > 0) {
            Logradouro logradouro = (Logradouro) listReturn.get(0);
            bean.setLogradouro(logradouro);
        }else{
            bean.setLogradouro(new Logradouro());
        }
    }
```

This is my component with onblur event:

```
<p:inputText value="#{enderecoMB.bean.logradouro.cep}" id="cep"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="O CEP é obrigatório">
                        <p:ajax event="blur"
                            listener="#{enderecoMB.carregarLogradouroByCep}"
                            update=":formManterEndereco:logradouro, :formManterEndereco:cidade, :formManterEndereco:estado, 
                        :formManterEndereco:bairro" />
                    </p:inputText>
```

I have a "BasicDAOImpl" that make all operations in database, so tried do it in my entityManager:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init(){        
        entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    }
```

But "update automatically" continue.

EDIT 2: My FIND_BY_CEP query

```
"SELECT c FROM Endereco c JOIN FETCH c.tipoEndereco JOIN FETCH c.logradouro"
```

EDit 3: My Entities

Endereco.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = { @NamedQuery(name = "Endereco.findAllCompleto", query = "SELECT c FROM Endereco c "
        + "JOIN FETCH c.tipoEndereco " + "JOIN FETCH c.logradouro") })
@Table(name = "endereco")
public class Endereco extends AbstractBean {



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5239354646908722819L;

    public Endereco(){
        logradouro = new Logradouro();
    }

    @Transient
    public static final String FIND_ALL_COMPLETO = "Endereco.findAllCompleto";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_endereco")
    private TipoEndereco tipoEndereco;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_logradouro")
    private Logradouro logradouro;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    @Column
    private String numero;

    @Column
    private String complemento;

    public Logradouro getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(Logradouro logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public TipoEndereco getTipoEndereco() {
        return tipoEndereco;
    }

    public void setTipoEndereco(TipoEndereco tipoEndereco) {
        this.tipoEndereco = tipoEndereco;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }



}
```

Logradouro.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = { @NamedQuery(name = "Logradouro.findByCep", query = "SELECT c FROM Logradouro c "
        + "JOIN FETCH c.bairro "
        + "JOIN FETCH c.cidade "
        + "WHERE c.cep = :cep "
        + "ORDER BY c.logradouro") })
@Table(name = "logradouro")
public class Logradouro extends AbstractBean {

    public Logradouro(){
        this.cidade = new Cidade();
        this.bairro = new Bairro();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Transient
    public static final String FIND_BY_CEP = "Logradouro.findByCep";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cidade")
    private Cidade cidade;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_bairro")
    private Bairro bairro;

    @Column
    private String cep;

    @Column
    private String logradouro;

    public Cidade getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public Bairro getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(Bairro bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Makky,i posted all code necessary

Comment: show us the named query "FIND_BY_CEP"

Comment: Also check you might have trigger in your table.

Comment: I don't have any trigger.

Comment: no. The DB updated is triggred when i make " bean.getLogradouro().getCep()"

Comment: I don't know how can i explain it for you, but the only problem is that hibernate is executing the update after executed "getCep()", because i changed the value of CEP from JSF page.

Comment: i edited my post with my entities. @AndreiI, i don't have access to entityManager in my "ManagedBean", this is a DAO attribute.

Comment: Try em.clear() to detach all entities immediately after you read them in.  This will allow changes to occur without them being associated to the active transaction.  You might also want to manage your transactions and entityManagers so that reads occur outside a transaction.

Comment: As i can said, this problem happens when i try do it: "query.getResultList()" from a Query Object. If i do "entityManager.clear()" before this method getResultList(). If i make "em.clear()" all my entities will be "detached", and probaly this is not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses an entitymanager to do automatic handling of your entities by default. Your bean is one such entity so whenever the entitymanager feels it's time to flush to the database it does so. If you want to flush manually, you'll want to have a look at such a construction:

```
entityManager.setFlushMode(javax.persistence.FlushModeType.MANUAL);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good ideia leaves the hibernate do the "commit" automatically, at least for my bussiness rules. I will try this "FlushModeType.COMMIT" and return here.

Comment: I tried do it (edited my post with more information) but the update continue happens, but now update occurrs after "SELECT statement".

Answer (score 0):

I think that you misuse Hibernate. The main idea of ORM that is allows you to write code, ignoring that fact, that something goes into database. Your domain model must be completetly testable without any database. ORM is not abstraction to manage with relation database, it is abstraction for your object model. If you need to explicitly do `insert`s and `updates`, you better use some active record implementation or look at lightweight mapper like `MyBatis`.

And why you want to prevent database update? Property is changed, right? So let Hibernate decide, whether and when its new value must be written to database.

Comment: The problem is: In JSF i mapped all my components with a bean called "Logradouro" that was found by a ZIP CODE. When user type another ZIP CODE this object LOGRADOURO must be replaced and don't updated.

Comment: When i make "getResultList()' in Query object, the update happens.

Comment: I doubt if it is good practice to bind domain entities straight to forms. It is better to map to DTOs and copy data from DTO to entities each time user pushes 'Sumbit' or 'Save' button. Maybe changing your approach this way could solve the issue.